# Null Reference Exception openFileDialog

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

### Code:

```
namespace bla_bla_bla

{   public delegate void pathSelected(string path);
 //...
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      public pathSelected onPath;
 //...
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter ="Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF";
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    if (openFileDialog1.SafeFileName != null)
    onPath(openFileDialog1.SafeFileName);
  }
```

### Question:

Why am I getting a `null` reference exeption in the last row?

### Error:

(Original poster should add such here)

Comment: What is `onPath`? And did you try debugging and checking if `onPath` or `openFileDialog1` has become `null` (last there is most unlikely). I'm going to guess that `onPath` is of type `pathSelected`, but you haven't assigned it a value yet, so it is `null`.

Comment: guess "onPath" is really "pathSelected", he's trying to call the delegate I supouse

Comment: why do you call `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` twice?

Comment: Are you supposed to put in pathSelected onPath somewhere?

Comment: Also, note that your parameter to `pathSelected` is labelled "path", yet, `SafeFileName` does not include the path, it will only return the filename and extension.

Comment: also, you set `openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;` but you use `openFileDialog1.SafeFileName` instead of `.SafeFileNames`. this only returns the first selected file

Comment: onPath does not work regardless of the content, onPath is a field of Form1 class

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't fully understand your question, or why go need a delegate, but try something like this on your Button1 click event handler:

```
int size = -1;
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); 
if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    try {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
        size = text.Length;
    }
    catch (IOException) {
    }
}
```